# Generate Gui from c++ header files

Tags: c++, user-interface

Is there a project that reads a c++ header and generates GUI based on some XML schema?

Comment: what type of GUI do you expect it to build?

Comment: A table of editable textfields based on public vars

Comment: And what does the final gui actually do with the public vars?

Comment: pls accept answers to your other questions

Comment: Displays or sets the variables

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but I can almost guarantee that such a tool doesn't exist. Most attempts to make auto-generators like this only end up frustrating developers who would prefer to customize their gui anyway. Also dealing with custom data types is probably more hassle than it's worth, and very common in most C++ apps. I really do hope someone corrects me though, if there's some django admin-like interface for C++ objects that would be pretty cool.

Comment: I was thinking of building one with reflection but there arent any gd reflection libs for c++

Comment: BOOST has a good compile-time reflection library, which I imagine is all you'd need reflection for in such the case. I can't point you in any particular direction, but if you google BOOST Compile-Time Reflection you're sure to get some results. I.e, take a look at their type\function traits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BOOST for compile-time reflection, using this I imagine you could build some sort of front-end for accessing the global variables. I know it must be possible, at least to some degree, using BOOST. If not directly, definitely through the boost-python library. Take a look at their type\function traits